# GameTime Replacement / Wrapper for Pausing , Slow-mo and 'Fast-mo'

Tags: xna, c#, timestep, time-travel

I'm looking to change the way in which my game uses `GameTime` to run the game so that I can easily pause the game (`elapsedTime = 0`) or change how slow/fast the in game elements interact as a scaler of the actual time passed (`elapsedTime *= timeScale`).

In my project, I always make the assumption that the game is not running on a fixed time step for a number of reasons. Due to this, any changes of states have the elapsed time factored in from `GameTime`. I'm hoping this means I can simply simulate slow-mo, fast-mo, force short freezes (like when you kill an enemy in TLoZ: Windwaker - there's a short pause for emphasis) or pause the game by interfering with the `GameTime.ElapsedGameTime` that all of my `Update()` code uses.

My first thought is to stop using `GameTime` within any update code, and to instead wrap a new class (`MyTime`) around `GameTime`.

`MyTime` would do the following:

- Seperates real time and game time. Real time is the passage of time outside of the system. Game time is the passage of time within the game's world, i.e if slow motion is in effect, the time passed within the game would be lower for the period of slow motion.
- Time scaling can either be started and ended, or requested to be active for a length of real time or game time.
- Time can be paused or frozen with either manual start and stop calls, or for a length of time, again based on either real or game time.

[Based on this discussion](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/10587.aspx), where it's states that `GameTime` is recreated every tick within XNA's base `Game` class, I'm hestitant to just store a reference to `GameTime` within `MyTime` as I personally don't know how `GameTime` is altered. I also don't know the 'best' way to retrieve the `GameTime` reference in the first place, the reference is available within the `Update()` and `Draw()` calls, however since `gameTime` isn't made available throughout any derived from `Game` class, it's implied taking the `gameTime` reference out of those update and draw calls isn't intended.

Is my intended implementation of this the right way of achieveing this system? What is a good to expose `GameTime` to `MyTime`? Should I implement my own way to track time and not rely on `GameTime` at all?

Answer (score 2):

I would still use `GameTime` to track the passage of time (no sense reinventing that wheel), but I would not bother storing it in your `MyTime` object and you certainly shouldn't try to subclass `GameTime`. Just create your own type with whatever fields you want and then use the `GameTime` provided to the `Game` class to update your instance however you want, applying your time scale, etc. This gives you full customization of the timing structure without having to worry about how the `Game` stores/updates the `GameTime` object.

Edit:
Humorously I'm going against my own advice in that link but you learn a thing or two from six additional years of game development. So listen to me by not listening to me. :)